# Expected value of betting odds

Tags: expected-value, gambling

Say you have $n$ to $m$ odds of winning. The expected value is computed as

$$
E[profit] = p_{winning}*n + (1-p_{winning})*-m
$$

I am confused why it is $p_{winning}*n$ instead of $p_{winning}*(n+m)$. Doesn't the former imply that you don't get your $m$ back if you win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because we're talking about the expected profit or loss, so the return of the stake doesn't enter into it.

Here's an example.  Say a roulette wheel has $18$ black numbers, $18$ red numbers and $1$ green number.  If you bet on black the probability of winning is $\frac{18}{37}$ and the house pays even money, that is $1$ to $1$.  In $37$ plays, we expect to win $18$ times and lose $19$ times so, the expectation is $-\frac1{37}$.  We have $n=m=1$, and the formula gives$$1\cdot\frac{18}{37}-1\cdot\frac{19}{37}=-\frac1{37}$$ as claimed.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm new to the concept of "betting odds," but in some articles I read some people are claiming that "betting odds" also represent the probability of winning. Is this generally true or untrue?

Comment: @David Sometimes people talk about the "odds" when they mean the probability.  Poker players talk about the odds of filling a flush when you draw one card, for example.  I think it's less confusing to reserve the term to convey the wager you have to make to win a stated amount.  People seem to find it hard to understand that odds of $3:1$ is the same as a probability of $\frac14$.